# Unit testing asynchronous Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

First iteration of this question: [Unit testing Angular directive with $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478319/unit-testing-angular-directive-with-http)

I created a directive that, when bound to an input, responds to blur/keyup events by calling a service before modifying the DOM. This service relies on $http and is therefore asynchronous. I've written a functional unit test for the service, but for the life of me I can't write a working test for the directive.

```
describe('SignupForm directives', function () { 
    var form,       // el to which directive is applied
    scope,
    userService,
    el;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('signupform.directives');
});

beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function ($injector, $rootScope, $compile, $q, $timeout) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        el = $compile('<input id="username" type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" sg-valid-username />')(scope);

        userService = $injector.get('userService');
        scope.user = { username: 'test_username' };
        spyOn(userService, 'checkIfUserExists');
    });
});

   it('Directive fires on blur', function() {
    scope.$digest();

    // build blur event and fire it
    var blurEvent = $.Event('blur');
    angular.element(el).triggerHandler(blurEvent);

    expect(userService.checkIfUserExists).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I have proven using the debugger that the service—userService.checkIfUserExists—gets called. It's just the expect() happens before then and fails the test.

I have no clue how to write this asynchronously, though. Jasmine 2.0's done() concept is mind-boggling, and userService does not otherwise need a callback to pass in.

How can I approach this?

Comment: Add `scope.$digest()` after `angular.element(el).triggerHandler(blurEvent);`

Comment: @merlin: I moved scope.$digest() after that line and before the expect(), then reran karma. Error is still the same: Expected spy checkIfUserExists to have been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout` in your driective, so that you can manually flush the pending timeout in unit tests.

```
.directive('sgValidUsername', ['$timeout', 'userService', function ($timeout, userService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function(scope, element) {
            var promise;
            element.on('blur keyup', function(e) {
              $timeout.cancel(promise);
              promise = $timeout(function() {
                userService.checkIfUserExists();
              }, 1000);
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

In your unit test, call [`$timeout.flush()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) after `el.triggerHandler('blur')` to manually trigger the timeout callback(which calls your `checkIfUserExists`).

```
it('Directive fires on blur', function() {
  el.triggerHandler('blur');
  $timeout.flush();//Flush pending timeouts
  expect(userService.checkIfUserExists).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ln1LHX8nKeOznllAA5Vc?p=preview) for a full working example.

Comment: Brilliant! I had never even heard of $timeout. Thanks.